# Greek alphabet: tonos and oxia

Tags: luatex

I have a font that includes the Greek alphabet where monotonic glyphs have slightly different accents from polytonic ones.

When I compose with Lualatex in polytonic, however, the "double" glyphs are taken from the monotonic anyway. More precisely, the glyphs with tonos and not those with oxia are also used in polytonic: this generates some lack of homogeneity in the text.

So I made an experiment with EB Garamond (where monotonic and polytonic accents have a slight difference) to better highlight the problem by replacing the monotonic accents with bullets, and while filling in with the option for polytonic, the vowels with the acute accent they bear the bullet.

So I used a replacement rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[greek.polutoniko]{babel}
%\usepackage[greek.ancient]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\sinoxia {EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\oxia [RawFeature={+tonosoxia}]{EB Garamond}

\directlua {
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
name = "tonosoxia",

type = "substitution",
data = {
alphatonos = "ά",
epsilontonos = "έ",
etatonos = "ή",
iotatonos = "ί",
omicrontonos = "ό",
omegatonos = "ώ",
upsilontonos = "ύ",
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}

\sinoxia

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ

\oxia

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ

\end {document}
```

However, nothing happens: the replacement rule seems to have no consequences.

[image]

Is there something wrong with the rule itself, or does the replacement not take place for some other reason?

Thank you

Comment: the syntax is false, `["alphatonos"] = "ά",`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The other syntax works too.

Comment: When I look at the Unicode codepoints in your substitution rule, then you are trying to replace "alphatonos" with "ά", aka. Unicode codepoint U+03AC, aka "GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH TONOS". Of course, this one will still have a tonos. If you want an oxia, use U+1F71 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH OXIA. You probably want to write "\u{1F71}" instead of "ά" to stop your editor from interfering.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger oh, are the glyph name variables?

Comment: Your issue in general seems to be with your editor and not LuaLaTeX: Probably you editor normalizes the file before saving and in Unicode, alpha with oxia gets normalized to alpha with tonos.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, in a Lua table definition, `{abc="def"}` is syntactic sugar for `{["abc"]="def"}`. (That is the reason why we need the brackets there: To distinguish from the string form.)

Comment: ulrikefischer thank you for your correction @MarcelKrüger You have seen well. In fact, from a new test, I realized that if I write the letter with the editor (for example alpha + oxia) using keyboard shortcuts, the problem occurs again and the replacement does not take place. If instead I make a copy-past from a site of the same letter, then the problem does not arise. How to prevent the editor from normalizing?

Comment: so, to use U+1F71, which correct form have I to adopt?

Comment: @user41063 That depends on which editor it is. Unfortunately, it’s not really a TeX question, so we might not know the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases, your editor and/or OS will normalize your input into some Unicode normal form (typically NFC). In Unicode, the characters with tonos and oxia are canonically equivalent, so you will always end up with tonos in your output.

Adding a substitution rule is a good idea to recover the oxia, but you have to make sure that the replacement isn't normalized itself. One approach for this is to specify the replacement though Unicode codepoint numbers instead of typing the actual characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[greek.polutoniko]{babel}
%\usepackage[greek.ancient]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\sinoxia {EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\oxia [RawFeature={+tonosoxia}]{EB Garamond}

\directlua {
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
  name = "tonosoxia",
  % features = {grek = {pgr = true}}, % Restrict the change to Polytonic Greek. Doesn't work here because babel only sets the language to greek
  type = "substitution",
  data = {
    Alphatonos = 0x1FBB,
    Epsilontonos = 0x1FC9,
    Etatonos = 0x1FCB,
    Iotatonos = 0x1FDB,
    Omicrontonos = 0x1FF9,
    Omegatonos = 0x1FFB,
    Upsilontonos = 0x1FEB,
    alphatonos = 0x1F71,
    epsilontonos = 0x1F73,
    etatonos = 0x1F75,
    iotatonos = 0x1F77,
    iotadieresistonos = 0x1FD3,
    omicrontonos = 0x1F79,
    omegatonos = 0x1F7D,
    upsilontonos = 0x1F7B,
    upsilondieresistonos = 0x1FE3,
  },
}
}
\begin{document}
\showoutput

\sinoxia

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ

\oxia

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ

\end {document}
```

Comment: As to `features = {grek = {pgr = true}}`, please could you provide a pointer where this syntax is described?

Comment: It seems to work perfecly! Thanx a lot

Comment: @JavierBezos It's actually documented: See `texdoc fonts-mkiv`, 8.14.5 ("Language dependencies")

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I didn't doubt it, but I couldn't find it. It didn't occur to me to look in the Context manuals. Thanks.

Comment: @JavierBezos Then you were much more optimistic than I was, because I was pretty sure that it is undocumented...

Comment: WRT `babel`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542882/tags-for-polytonic-greek-with-babel/543023#543023