# Tags for polytonic Greek with babel

Tags: babel, greek

Composing with Lualatex + fontspec + babel, the options to pass for the Greek language (if I'm not wrong) should be: `greek`, `greek.polutoniko` and `greek.ancient`.

Now, as you know, there are substitution mechanisms (some types of lookups) inside the fonts that are activated either with certain options in the text (for example `RawFeature=+calt`), or simply by calling a certain language. An example is the mechanism whereby by setting the language to Turkish with `\selectlanguage{turkish}` the command `\MakeLowercase{II}` transforms the capital letter < I > into a lowercase dottless letter < ı >. This is because in the font there is a replacement lookup valid for `latn{ TRK}`.

I have created in the font a replacement lookup valid for `grek{ PGR}` = for polytonic Greek, so that monotonic uses vowels with the acute accent tonos, while polytonic uses vowels with the acute accent oxia. This lookup (a single substitution or `'locl'`) should be activated when Greek is not monotonic.

The problem is that if I set `\usepackage[greek.polutoniko]{babel}` the mechanism does not work, ie in this case Lualatex does not seem to recognize that, being the polytonic Greek language, it should apply the substitution rule. In short, the font tag `latn{ TRK}` triggers the substitution when the language is Turkish, but the font tag `grek{ PGR}` does not trigger it when the language is polytonic Greek.

I ask (if I was clear enough) how it's possible to tag the text in a way that invokes inside the text the PGR language system feature lookups which is present inside the font.

Thank you

**Addendum**

Minimal (not) working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{polytonicgreek}
\newfontlanguage{Polutoniko}{PGR}
\babelfont[italian]{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+supkern,RawFeature=+calt]{SimonciniGaramondPro} 
\babelfont[greek]{rm}[Language=Polutoniko,RawFeature=+calt]{SimonciniGaramondPro}

\begin{document}

quel ramo del lago di Como

\selectlanguage{greek}

ά ὰ έ ὲ

\end{document}
```

Exit:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language nil yet.
(babel)                Perhaps you misspelled it or your installation
(babel)                is not complete.
```

**Addendum 2**

Thanks to your indications, it seems that I managed to solve. I apologize if I have not always understood these indications immediately. Furthermore, the matter was complicated by the fact that I had to create the right interaction between the font lookups and the Lualatex code.

This is the final code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\babelprovide[import, main]{italian}
\babelprovide[import]{polytonicgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{greek}
\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{SimonciniGaramondPro}
\babelfont[polytonicgreek]{rm}[RawFeature=+calt]{SimonciniGaramondPro}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}[RawFeature=+calt]{SimonciniGaramondPro}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ 

\selectlanguage{polytonicgreek}

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ

ά ὰ έ ὲ

\end{document}
```

As you can see from the image, on the left Adobe Garamond Premiere Pro itself presents the problem of using in the polytonic the acute accents of the monotonic, slightly different from the polytonic causing a lack of homogeneity in the rendering (see the third line).
On the right the final rendering of the font I'm working on.

[image]

**One last question: since the main language is Italian, is it correct to enter it directly as a babel option without using `\babelprovide`?**

Thanks for your cooperation and your patience :)

Comment: Please, edit your post to add a MWE. Without it it's difficult to say and to propose a solution, but with the alternative `\babelprovide[import,main]{polytonicgreek]` `babel` does set the language to `PGR` (or at least it attempts to do so). It looks much like a problem in the font side.

Comment: All right, Javier Bezos seems to have figured it out, but the MNWE wasn’t compiling because it defines `polutonicgreek` but uses `greek`. However, `polutonicgreek` should not need the workaround.

Comment: do you mean to use `\babelfont[polytonicgreek]{rm}[Language=Polutoniko,RawFeature=+calt]{SimonciniGaramondPro}`? It produces the same error

Comment: in some cases I don't know how to move and I work by trial and error, not being able to interpret your suggestions well. You recommend me to use `{polytonicgreek}`: but I don't find it in the babel manual: where does it come from? You recommend me to use `\newfontlanguage{Polutoniko}{PGR}`, but in the fontspec manual (8.2) Iread `\ newfontlanguage {Zulu} {ZUL}
The first argument is the fontspec name, the second the OpenType tag`. And Polutoniko is not a fontspec name. So I don't understand how to proceed...

Comment: @user41063 (1) As to the problem with 'nil', try deleting the `aux` file; if it still fails, very likely your system in broken. (2) As to the original question, is there any reason to ignore my answer altogether?

Comment: Absolutely not: in fact, I replaced the language attribute with \ babelprovide

Comment: Loading `italian` as a package option is fine, and the recommended way if it works for you (not always does, and `greek` is a case in point). Sadly, I haven't got `SimonciniGaramondPro` (only the Std, without Greek), so I can't test.

Comment: Thank you! SImonciniGaramondPro doesn't exist properly. It's a "private" font I'm working about.

Comment: For polytonic Greek is not ancient Greek (even if the latter is polytonic too), but there is nothing - I think - as \babelprovide[import]{ancientgreek} or similar, how can I load the correct hypenation pattern for ancient Greek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've realized your question was related to [Greek alphabet: tonos and oxia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542789/greek-alphabet-tonos-and-oxia/542802#542802) . Please, don't forget to include a MWE and links to related questions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\babelprovide[import, main]{polytonicgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{greek}

\directlua {
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
  name = "tonosoxia",
  features = {grek = {pgr = true}}, 
  type = "substitution",
  data = {
    Alphatonos = 0x1FBB,
    Epsilontonos = 0x1FC9,
    Etatonos = 0x1FCB,
    Iotatonos = 0x1FDB,
    Omicrontonos = 0x1FF9,
    Omegatonos = 0x1FFB,
    Upsilontonos = 0x1FEB,
    alphatonos = 0x1F71,
    epsilontonos = 0x1F73,
    etatonos = 0x1F75,
    iotatonos = 0x1F77,
    iotadieresistonos = 0x1FD3,
    omicrontonos = 0x1F79,
    omegatonos = 0x1F7D,
    upsilontonos = 0x1F7B,
    upsilondieresistonos = 0x1FE3,
  },
}
}

\babelfont{rm}[RawFeature=+calt;+tonosoxia]{EB Garamond}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}[RawFeature=+calt]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ 

\selectlanguage{greek}

ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ

\end {document}
```

Unfortunately, the standard Greek style loads the languages is a somewhat tricky way which the `babel` core is unable to catch to set the font language system, but the alternative based on `\babelprovide` sets it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit

Javier Bezos, the maintainer of `babel`, showed up in the comments to recommend the command

```
\babelprovide[import,main]{polytonicgreek}
```

This should set the language tag correctly. Remove `main` if it should not be the main language.

#### Original Answer

If you have font-specific features, you can select them as options when you load that font through `\babelfont`.  If every Greek font in your program should load the same OpenType language tag, you can also load the Greek language with `\babelprovide[import, language=...]`.

Since there is no predefined interface in `fontspec` for the language tag `PGR`, you would want to define it with a command like:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontlanguage{Polutoniko}{PGR}
```

after loading `babel` and before invoking

```
\babelfont[greek]{rm}
          [Language=Polutoniko]{MyCustomFont.otf}
```

Comment: Du you mean something like the following code, but which is not working? Or have I misunderstood your solution: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[greek.polutoniko]{babel}
\newfontlanguage{Polutoniko}{PGR}

\babelfont[greek.polutoniko]{rm}[Language=Polutoniko,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{EB Garamond}
Garamond}

\begin{document}


ά έ ή ί ό ώ ύ

\end{document}`

Comment: It looks like you might have an extra `Garamond` in there, and as of last I heard it was preferable to load `fontspec` after `babel`, but something like that. Does it work? I don’t have the custom font to test with.

Comment: You're right, a error in copy/past. The following code `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontlanguage{Greek}{PGR}
\babelfont[greek.ancient]{rm}[Language=Greek,RawFeature=+calt]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

ά ὰ έ ὲ

\end{document}` produces an error: `! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language nil yet.`

Comment: Javier Bezos, the maintainer of `babel`, says that the `Language=` tag should not have been the issue. Unfortunately, without the MWE or the font, I cannot troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: However, your second example sets `Language=Greek` instead of the `Language=Polutoniko` you just defined.

Comment: Suggest me a font you have. In any case EBGaramond is free

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontlanguage{Polutoniko}{PGR}
\babelfont[greek.ancient]{rm}[Language=Polutoniko,RawFeature=+calt]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

ά ὰ έ ὲ

\end{document}` gives me the same error: `! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language nil yet.`

Comment: No errors for me. Anyway, see my comment to the question. BTW, the language is named `greek`. not `greek.ancient`. For Greek, `\babelprovide` can be often a better choice.

Comment: @JavierBezos The OP said that the package provides `greek.ancient` as a variant? I wasn't aware that thus would break anything?

Comment: @Davislor But the style for Greek actually creates a language named `greek`.

Comment: @JavierBezos in the past, you’ve told me to load languages as package options instead of with `\babelprovide`. It’s really not optimal if some languages work only one way, some work only the other way, and which one we’re supposed to use at any given time is undocumented.

Comment: @Davislor You are quite right. The recommended way is loading the ldf files, but if they don't work for you using the ini locale files is an alternative.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thank you for your help! I edited my answer.

Comment: Infact I'm using a font I'm working around, with greek lookups. So you can't have it

Comment: I'm a bit confused... language option or \babelprovide? In any case: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{greek}
\newfontlanguage{Polutoniko}{PGR}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}[Language=Polutoniko,RawFeature=+calt]{SimonciniGaramondPro}

\begin{document}

ά ὰ έ ὲ

\end{document}` produces and empty file and not load my font: `</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.
otf>`

Comment: Can you be kind enough to produce a complete MWE?

Comment: @user41063 Actually it's you who have to provide the MWE. But anyway, have you seen my answer?

Comment: Add e M(not)WE in my original question